# In facelets, how do I fetch from a HashMap where keys are of DataType Short

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, el

I am getting an javax.el.ELException: java.lang.Short cannot be cast to java.lang.Long for the following code:

```
<ui:param name="aumSegmentType" value="#{segmentSetup.userSegmentTypes[2]}" />
```

I am using Mojarra 2.1, facelets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. Numbers are in EL by [specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html) treated as `Long`.

If changing the map key type isn't an option, then you need to create a method which takes a `long` and casts it to `short`.

```
public SomeObject getUserSegmentType(long key) {
    return userSegmentTypes.get((short) key);
}
```

and use it as follows

```
<ui:param ... value="#{segmentSetup.getUserSegmentType(2)}" />
```

I of course assume that your environment already supports EL 2.2. It should, given the fact that you're using JSF 2.1.

Note that this problem is unrelated to JSF/Facelets.